# Astroid area with Green Theorem

Tags: calculus, area, greens-theorem

I know that the area of an astroid can be calculated by Green's theorem through the integral: $$ A =  \frac{3a^2}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}[\cos^4t \sin^2t+\sin^4t\cos^2t]dt$$.

However, I found the following expression in the class notes of a former teacher of mine: $$ A =  \frac{3a^2}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}[1-\cos^2(2t)]dt$$

This integral results in the appropriate area: $\frac{3a^2 \pi}{8}$, as well as the first integral. However, I could not understand if this second integral does in fact make sense. Can you help me understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a match and both the answers are correct since
$$
{
\cos^4 x\sin^2x+\sin^4 x\cos^2x=
\\\cos^2 x\sin^2x(\cos^2 x+\sin^2x)=
\\\cos^2 x\sin^2x=
{1\over 4}\sin^2 2x=\\
{1\over 4}(1-\cos^2 2x)
}
$$
Note that the integral bounds have changed to lead to a same answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the substitution $$u=t-\pi$$

$\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)dt$ becomes $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(u)du$

the integrand is an even function, so, it gives
$$2\int_0^{\pi}f(u)du$$

A new substitution $ v=u-\frac{\pi}{2}$

gives $$2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(v)dv$$
and finally

$$4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(v)dv$$